# WPF combobox - jump to typed char when concatenating using ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, combobox

When using DisplayMemberPath, it works as expected - it jumps to the typed character, but in the following case i need to concatenate two fields, Surname and Name and would like to jump to the Surname, but it is not working. Anyone knows a solution? Here is the example:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.AllDoctors}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Doctor.Id}" SelectedValuePath="Id" >
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Surname"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Name"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>                                
                            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [`TextSearch.TextPath` attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textsearch.textpath) to your `ComboBox` and
set `IsTextSearchEnabled` to `True`.

```
<ComboBox IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Surname" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.AllDoctors}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Doctor.Id}" SelectedValuePath="Id" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Surname"/>
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```